# symfony2 search form querybuilder with parameters

Tags: symfony, controller, repository, query-builder, dql

here's a picture of the page on the left i have a form when submitted i want it to display the found vehicles on the right side using the informations entered by the user else if the user does not go to the form the page shows all the cars .in both cases the user should only sees cars where price is not 0

[image]

this is my form in case needed but i have no problem here VoitureType3.php :

```
$builder
->add('marque', EntityType::class,array(
        'class' => 'SpoiledCarFrontOfficeBundle:Marque',
        'required'      => true, 
        'empty_value'   => '== Choisissez une Marque ==',
         ))

       ->add('modele', DependentFormsType::class,array(
       'entity_alias'   => 'modele_by_marque',
       'parent_field'   => 'marque',
       'empty_value'    => '== Choisissez un Modele =='


         ))
    ->add('chevaux', 'choice', array( 'choices' => array('4' => '4', '5' => '5', '6' => '6', '7' => '7', '8' => '8', '9' => '9', '10' => '10', '11' => '11', '12' => '12', '13' => '13', '14' => '14', '15' => '15', '16' => '16'),'expanded' => false, 'required' => true,
     'multiple' => false,   'label' => 'Nombre de Chevaux' )) 
    ->add('boitevitesse', 'choice', array( 'choices' => array('Automatique' => 'Automatique', 'Manuelle' => 'Manuelle', 'Sequentielle' => 'Sequentielle'),'expanded' => false, 'required' => true,
     'multiple' => false,   'label' => 'Boite de Vitesse' ))
```

here's my controller :

```
  $filterForm = $this->createForm('SpoiledCar\FrontOfficeBundle\Form\VoitureType3');

 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $voiturefind = $em->getRepository('SpoiledCarFrontOfficeBundle:Voiture')->myFindAll($filterForm);
 $voitures  = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate($voiturefind,$this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),6); 

// Bind values from the request
$filterForm->handleRequest($request);

 if ($filterForm->isSubmitted() && $filterForm->isValid()) {
  return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:listTable.html.twig', array(
        'voitures' => $voitures,


 ));
   }
   return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:listTable.html.twig', array(
        'voitures' => $voitures,
        'filterForm' => $filterForm->createView(),

  ));
```

i'm getting this error :

```
  Attempted to call an undefined method named "andWhere" of class "Doctrine\ORM\Query".
```

and this is my querybuilder i think the problem come from here but i don't know what i'm doing wrong exactly

```
public function myFindAll(FormInterface $filterForm)
{

  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->Where('p.prix IS NOT NULL')
    ->getQuery();
 if ($filterForm->has('marque')) {
 $qb->andWhere( $qb->expr()->like('u.marque', ':marque'))
  ->setParameter('marque', '%'. $filterForm->get('marque')->getData().'%');
  }
  if ($filterForm->has('modele')) {
 $qb->andWhere( $qb->expr()->like('u.modele', ':modele'))
 ->setParameter('modele', '%'. $filterForm->get('modele')->getData().'%');
  }

 if ($filterForm->has('boitevitesse')) {
 $qb->andWhere( $qb->expr()->like('u.boitevitesse', ':boitevitesse'))
->setParameter('boitevitesse', '%'. $filterForm->get('boitevitesse')- >getData().'%');
  }

 if ($filterForm->has('chevaux')) {
$qb->andWhere( $qb->expr()->like('u.chevaux', ':chevaux'))
->setParameter('chevaux', '%'. $filterForm->get('chevaux')->getData().'%');
}

return $qb->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getQuery() method is called before the rest of optionnal expressions...

Try to "move it" :

```
public function myFindAll(FormInterface $filterForm)
{
     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

     /***/

     return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: okay i'm getting another error ps:marque and modele are other tables joined by foreign key to table voiture [Semantical Error] line 0, col 91 near 'marque LIKE :marque': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Comment: `like('u.marque', ':marque')` <- why `u`? Where do you find it?

Comment: i fixed that i forget about that i changed them to p but nom i'm getting that error when i remove marque and modele it works !!

Comment: What is the error if you don't remove `marque` & `modele`?

Comment: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 91 near 'marque LIKE :marque': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Comment: Concerning `marque` it seems you have a relation between Marque Entity and the initial Entity in which you make your request. A join should be the solution. But I don't know the mapping, so...

Comment: here's the realtion between marque and voiture i'm a beginner using querybuilder so don't know exactly what to do :
    manyToOne:
      marque:
        targetEntity: Marque
        inversedBy: voiture
        joinColumn:
          name: marque_id
          referencedColumnName: id

Comment: `if ($filterForm->has('marque')) {
 $qb->leftJoin('p.marque', 'm')->andWhere( $qb->expr()->like('m.name', ':marque'))->setParameter('marque', '%'. $filterForm->get('marque')->getData().'%');
  }`  Something like that (Has the entity Marque contains a field name?)

Comment: lol just a sec now everything works but when i click on filter he always shows me all the cars what i'm doing wrong he don't do the filter ?